# Tkinter pack add space beteen elements

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

If I'm using the tkinter pack manager and I just want to add some space horizontally between two items, what is the best way to do it? I understand padx, pady, ipadx, and ipady, but they add space AROUND an item on both sides. Unfortunately I don't see padleft, padright, anything of that nature to just add space BETWEEN two items. What is the best practice here? Just create a little frame and stick it between the visible items?

Comment: Did you know that you can use a tuple for `padx`. So `padx=(0, 5)` only puts a 5 pix padding on the right of the widget and none on the left. Same goes for `pady`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`padx` and `pady` can be a single value, or a tuple of two values. When given two values, `padx` uses the first value for the left and the second value for the right. Similarly, `pady` uses the first value for the top and the second value for the bottom.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Padding example")

label.pack(padx=(0, 100), pady=(100, 0))

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]